# How do I display custom RSS fields on my site?

Tags: customization, rss

I have an external site whose RSS I want to show on my wordpress site. There are many custom fields in the RSS XML such as

```
<av-sr:short_description>Ambiguous Dance Company</av-sr:short_description>
<av-sr:start_date>2018-06-08T20:00:00.000</av-sr:start_date>
```

How do I pull this data into a wordpress RSS feed? The plugins I tried so far only display basic things like "title" and "description."

Do I have to write my own plugin?

Comment: You may want to do a Google search for "wordpress import rss" and follow some of the links you get back as results. There are a lot of people plugging their own solutions which you have to pay for and I have not tested any of these enough to recommend one.

Comment: OK I had to create my own plugin writing PHP code. Checkout SIMPLEPIE functions for get custom tags.